# Как посчитать количество элементов COUNT(*) если есть HAVING и GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть 3 таблицы
**product**, **product_to_category**, **product_to_filter**

отношение таблицы **product** - один к многим

Задача состоит в том что нужно выбрать товары из категории, с учётом фильтров и количества их совпадения

Этот запрос есть, и успешно отрабатывает:

```
select 'product'.'product_id' from 'product' 
inner join 'product_to_category' on 'product'.'product_id' = 'product_to_category'.'product_id'
inner join 'product_to_filter' on 'product'.'product_id' = 'product_to_filter'.'product_id' 
where 'product_to_filter'.'filter_id' in (3,9) 
and 'product'.'status' = 1 
and 'product_to_category'.'category_id' = 8 
group by 'product'.'product_id' 
having COUNT('product_to_filter'.'filter_id') = 2 
order by 'product'.'sort_order' asc 
limit 10 offset 0
```

Теперь нужно посчитать количество товаров этого запроса.
Но столкнулся с проблемой, из-за **group by** приходит **несколько строк с количеством 1**.
Без group by не могу **так как есть having COUNT**.
Пробовал с флагом **with rollup**, тоже не помогает.
Есть идеи?

Comment: А не пробовали делать `SUM(COUNT('product'.'product_id'))` ?

Comment: Если версия позволяет - `COUNT(*) OVER ()`. Если нет - запихайте свой запрос в подзапрос.

Comment: @ArchDemon, не уверен что это оптимальный запрос при учете того что в магазине около 30тыс товаров

Comment: @Akina, версия к сожаниею не позволяет

Comment: Тогда подзапрос, куда деваться. PS. Вы, конечно, проигнорировали намёк... тогда скажу прямо - откорректируйте вопрос и укажите в нём точную версию MySQL.